# Запуск процесса Хрома с ключом, чтобы он открыл файл в конкретном окне

Tags: google-chrome

1. Открыт Хром - это первое окно.
2. Потом я программно запускаю процесс Хрома с ключом "--new-window" и путем к файлу - это
   открывает файл в новом окне Хрома. Это 2 окно.

   ```
    PR_START_INFO = New ProcessStartInfo
    PR_START_INFO.FileName = "...\chrome.exe"
    PR_START_INFO.Arguments = "--new-window " & File
    Process.Start(PR_START_INFO)
   ```

А потом мне надо открыть еще один файл во втором окне, но он открывается либо в первом окне, либо если с ключом "--new-window" то в третьем окне.
Есть ли способ запустить процесс Хрома (может с ключом каким-то), чтобы он открыл файл именно во втором окне в новой вкладке?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте опцию [`--user-data-dir`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#command-line). Запуск браузера с этой опцией создает в текущей директории папку с новым профилем пользователя. Выбирая между двумя профилями, можно управлять тем, в каком окне откроется сайт (проверял на Linux в браузере Chromium):

```bash
# Открываем сайт в первом окне:
chromium google.com --user-data-dir=profile1
```

```bash
# Открываем сайт во втором окне:
chromium google.com --user-data-dir=profile2
```

Как альтернативный вариант, чтобы не создавать два новых профиля, можно использовать дефолтный профиль и инкогнито-профиль:

```bash
# Открываем сайт в первом окне:
chromium google.com
```

```bash
# Открываем сайт во втором окне (инкогнито):
chromium google.com --incoginto
```